# Create a counter in sql with the recursive addition of row value based on a condition in BigQuery/SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In the below image, the 'output' column is the result I want to achive in sql. The 'LOGIC' column defines when to perform recursive addition and when to reset the counter to 1. Recursive addition is simply the current value of D + previous value of E. Resetting this counter to 1 in case column C is TRUE.

[image: sample data in excel with logic]

I have tried recursive CTEs and window function calls which works fine to get the counter value(D3+E2) but while resetting the counter to one it fails to do so. It simply countinues to get the counter. In the image I have makred the row where it fails.

[image: [![sample data with incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J2rv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J2rv.png)]

```
WITH RunningTotal AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    logic,
    val,
    SUM(CASE WHEN logic = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE val END) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS output
  FROM
    `my_table`
)

SELECT
  id,
  logic,
  val,
  output
FROM
  RunningTotal;
```

Comment: What SQL have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this logic works for me. Creating a temporary 'RunninTotal' function does the job for me.

```
WITH RunningTotal AS (
SELECT
    id,
    logic,
    val,
    CASE WHEN logic THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS reset_flag,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN logic THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS group_id 
  FROM `my_table`
)
SELECT
  id,
  logic,
  val,
  CASE WHEN logic THEN 1 
       ELSE SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY id)
  END AS output 
FROM RunningTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two window functions.

- separate the counting parts of the id's by the `logic` column. Each time the `logic` field is true, the value in the new column `logic_run` is increased by one.
- `sum_over` is the sum over each `logic_run` partition separately. Because you want to set the `val` to 1 if the `logic` is true, an `if` statement inside the sum is needed as shown for the `output` column.

```
WITH example_data AS (SELECT *,id in (2,6) as logic, mod(id-1,5) as val
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2,8)) AS id),
table1 as (
SELECT *, countif(logic) over win1 as logic_run
FROM example_data
window win1 as (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
)

SELECT *,
sum(val) over win2 as sum_over,
sum(if(logic,1,val)) over win2 as output
from table1
window win2 as (partition by logic_run order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```